# What is the right way to declare data that is an extension of another data

Tags: haskell

I am modelling a set of "things". For the most part all the things have the same characteristics.

```
data Thing = Thing { chOne :: Int, chTwo :: Int }
```

There is a small subset of things that can be considered to have an "extended" set of characteristics in addition to the base set shared by all members.

```
chThree :: String
```

I'd like to have functions that can operate on both kinds of things (these functions only care about properties `chOne` and `chTwo`):

```
foo :: Thing -> Int
```

I'd also like to have functions that operate on the kind of things with the `chThree` characteristic.

```
bar :: ThingLike -> String
```

I could do

```
data ThingBase = Thing { chOne :: Int, chTwo :: Int }
data ThingExt  = Thing { chOne :: Int, chTwo :: Int, chThree :: Int }
fooBase :: ThingBase -> Int
fooExt  :: ThingExt  -> Int
bar     :: ThingExt  -> String
```

But this is hideous.

I guess I could use type classes, but all the boilerplate suggests this is wrong:

```
class ThingBaseClass a of
  chOne' :: Int
  chTwo' :: Int

instance ThingBaseClass ThingBase where
  chOne' = chOne
  chTwo' = chTwo

instance ThingBaseClass ThingExt where
  chOne' = chOne
  chTwo' = chTwo

class ThingExtClass a of
  chThree' :: String

instance ThingExtClass ThingExt where
  chThree' = chThree

foo :: ThingBaseClass a => a -> Int
bar :: ThingExtClass  a => a -> String
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do so, is the equivalent of OO aggregation :

```
data ThingExt = ThingExt { thing :: Thing, chTree :: Int }
```

You can then create a class as in your post

```
instance ThingLike ThingExt where
     chOne' = chOne . thing
     chTwo' = chTwo . thing
```

If you are using the `lens` library you can use `makeClassy` which will generate all this boiler plate for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a data type that is a type union of the two distinct types of things:

```
data ThingBase = ThingBase { chBaseOne :: Int, chBaseTwo :: Int }
data ThingExt  = ThingExt { chExtOne :: Int, chExtTwo :: Int, chExtThree :: Int }
data ThingLike = CreatedWithBase ThingBase | 
                 CreatedWithExt ThingExt
```

Then for any function which should take *either* a `ThingBase` or a `ThingExt`, and do different things depending, you can do pattern matching on the type constructor:

```
foo :: ThingLike -> Int
foo (CreatedWithBase (ThingBase c1 c2)) = c1 + c2
foo (CreatedWithExt (ThingExt c1 c2 c3)) = c3

-- Or another way:
bar :: ThingLike -> Int
bar (CreatedWithBase v) = (chBaseOne v) + (chBaseTwo v)
bar (CreatedWithExt v) = chExtThree v
```

This has the *benefit* that it forces you to pedantically specify exactly what happens to `ThingBase`s or `ThingExt`s wherever they appear to be processed as part of handling a `ThingLike`, by creating the extra wrapping layer of constructors (the `CreatedWithBase` and `CreatedWithExt` constructors I used, whose sole purpose is to indicate which type of thing you expect at a certain point of code).

But it has the disadvantage that it doesn't allow for overloaded names for the field accessor functions. Personally I don't see this as too big of a loss, since the extra verbosity required to reference attributes acts like a natural complexity penalty and helps motivate the programmer to keep the code sparse and use fewer bad accessor/getter/setter anti-patterns. However, if you want to go far with overloaded accessor names, you should [look into lenses](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers_28.html).

This is just one idea and it's not right for every problem. The example you already give with type classes is also perfectly fine and I don't see any good reason to call it hideous.

Just about the only "bad" thing would be wanting to somehow implicitly process `ThingBase`s differently from `ThingExt`s without needing anything in the type signature or the pattern matching sections of a function body to explicitly tell people reading your code precisely when and where the two different types are differentiated, which would be more like a duck typing approach which is not really what you should do in Haskell.

This seems to be what you're trying to get at by trying to force both `ThingBase` and `ThingExt` to have a value constructor with the same name of just `Thing` -- it seems artificially nice that the same word can construct values of either type, but my feeling is it's not actually nice. I might be misunderstanding though.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to introduce a type parameter:

```
data ThingLike a = ThingLike { chOne, chTwo :: Int, chThree :: a }
  deriving Show
```

Then, a `ThingBase` is just a `ThingLike` with no third element, so

```
type ThingBase = ThingLike ()
```

`ThingExt` contains an additional `Int`, so

```
type ThingExt = ThingLike Int
```

This has the advantage of using only a single constructor and only three record accessors. There is minimal duplication, and writing your desired functions is simple:

```
foo :: ThingLike a -> Int 
foo (ThingLike x y _) = x+y

bar :: ThingExt -> String 
bar (ThingLike x y z) = show $ x+y+z
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Maybe ThingExt` field on `ThingBase` I guess, at least if you only have one extension type.

If you have several extensions like this, you can use a combination of embedding and matching on various constructors of the embedded data type, where each constructor represents one way to extend the base structure.

Once that becomes unmanageable, classes might become unevitable, but some kind of data type composition would still be useful to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
data Thing = Thing      { chOne :: Int, chTwo :: Int }
           | OtherThing { chOne :: Int, chTwo :: Int, chThree :: String }
```

Another is

```
data Thing = Thing { chOne :: Int, chTwo :: Int, chThree :: Maybe String }
```

If you want to distinguish the two `Thing`s *at the type level* and have overloaded accessors then you need to make use of a type class.

Comment: The first option is a bad idea, as named record and sum type leads to partial functions.

Comment: @mb14 it's not a "bad idea". `chTree` is the only partial function here. I agree that using/exporting it would be a bad idea.

Comment: The OP is planning to use those accessor, so exporting or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @mb14 "I'd like to have functions that can operate on both kinds of things (these functions only care about properties chOne and chTwo)"